# Case Insensitive - Sistema de Busca Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, case-insensitive

Bom dia!

Tenho este código que faz a busca dentro de uma lista `<ul> <li>`:

```
    $(function(){   

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){       

        var searchText = $(this).val();

        $('.filter-task > li').each(function(){

            var currentLiText = $(this).text(),
                showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

            $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        });

    });

});
```

Estou tentando tirar o case sensitive do jquery na busca, fazendo um busca pelo google achei este código:

```
    $.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Mas não entendi muito bem ele, alguém tem algo mais claro sobre o assunto, ou se tem alguma outra maneira de tirar o case sensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

para que a busca seja case-insensitive transforme o termo buscado e o texto do elemento em UPPERCASE ou lowercase

```
$(function(){   

$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){       

    var searchText = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

    $('.filter-task > li').each(function(){

        var currentLiText = $(this).text().toUpperCase(),
            showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;

        $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

    });

});

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Não precisa utiliza nenhuma função dessas, o javascript tem uma função nativa para deixar tudo caixa alta `toUpperCase()`

```js
$(function(){   

    $('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){       

        var searchText = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

        $('.filter-task > li').each(function(){

            var currentLiText = $(this).text().toUpperCase(),
                showCurrentLi = currentLiText.indexOf(searchText) !== -1;
      
            $(this).toggle(showCurrentLi);

        });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" >
<ul class="filter-task">
  <li>CACHORRO</li>
  <li>gato</li>
  <li>papagaio</li>
<ul>
```

Comment: Obrigado, mas se tiver algo para ler, também, sobre o assunto, agradeço.

Comment: Pra ler tem a documentação da Mozilla sobre uppercase https://mzl.la/2bJXuuT e sobre manipulação de string tem esse link https://mzl.la/2bPBxHX

Comment: Obrigado novamente